# fatal: in unpopulated submodule

Tags: angularjs, git, github

I am quite new to github and I am trying to find a solution to a current problem that I am having. I will go through my process step by step:

First I created a new folder named `[project name]`
Next I used these commands:

```
    cd [project name]
    git clone [remote project from github url]
```

So far I have created a folder and cloned a project that my group is working on in github.

Next, I went inside that folder and created an angular project with

```
    ng new [angulartest]
```

This will create all the components of my angular test into the same folder that is the clone of the one from github.

Finally, I pushed the new angular test on github with

```
    git add [angulartest]
    git commit
    git push
```

What happens is that it only pushes the folder `[angulartest]` but none of its contents (even though there are contents in it).  When I try to pull from its contents, I still just get an empty folder in return.

When I try to enter that folder and add each element of the contents, using these steps:

```
    cd [angulartest]
    git add e2e, src, nodemodules, etc
    git commit
    git push
```

It gives me the following error (even when I try to add each element individually):

`fatal: in unpopulated submodule [angulartest]`

I was wondering if it was a problem with my git syntax, the angular project, or the way I tried to clone the project.  That way, I know which direction I want to be headed when looking for a solution.

Comment: Root cause? According to  https://angular.io/cli/new... the `ng new [angulartest]` would have created a git repository inside the new directory (`--skip-git` is off by default)...

Answer (score 125):

It seems like, you may have removed the `.git` folder. In that case you can try

```
 git rm --cached angulartest -f
```

Comment: I had to go a few levels up to stage files.

Comment: Well, well, what do you know... this fixed everything for me! Thanks so much, `git` is tricky (but oh so useful!)

Comment: Thanks and it worked fine when I added a new project to the git folder, my mistake as it had been git init already and hence did not go to Github, but now it does
git rm --cached worked for me

Answer (score 80):

```
git rm --cached . -rf
```

Stealing from [anlijudavid's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789611/1310605) which was the actual answer for me on macOS with zsh.
Adding `-r` based on Richard Collette's comment to this answer.

Comment: fatal: not removing '.' recursively without -r

Comment: I had to add -r to use period.

Comment: @RichardCollette you are on Linux I'm guessing?

Comment: @eyecandy.dev MacOS

Comment: Thanks, 'git rm --cached .' did the trick

Answer (score 45):

The root cause of this error in my case was that I have a subdirectory with its own `.git` folder inside. When I issued the `git add --all` command, I got this same error

Here's how I resolved the issue

1. Remove all `.git` folder inside the sub directory causing the error
2. `cd` to the main directory
3. `git rm --cached sub_directory_name -f`
4. `git add --all` to add the subdirectory and contents, recursively
5. `git status` to verify that the items are added

I almost got a headache with this error but thanks for the previous answers, a combination of those worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

Here's what I did

1. Make a copy of the 'submodule' directory somewhere outside of the repository (e.g. your desktop)
2. Delete the submodule directory from your repo
3. Commit the repo
4. Go into the copy you made of your submodule directory, delete `.gitignore` file and `.git` directory
5. Copy the submodule directory back into your repo and commit

This meant I lost the commit history of the submodule but at least it fixed the issue of my files in the submodule not going to git!

Answer (score 16):

If we cloned from third party repository we got this " fatal: in unpopulated submodule 'submodule name' " error.

This error fix for me using

```
git rm --cached <submodule name> -f
```

Also you can remove *.git* folder manually then you can try to git add

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I had a subdirectory in my local repo, had deleted the .git to solve different issue, and then tried to add an updated html file to my repo.
I went to github and uploaded the file using their GUI. Now I can see that everyhting matches and git status shows no issues.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue when trying to push a new react-app folder to git.
Unfortanately, I overlooked the ".gitignore" files in the folders.

First check for files:

```
find | grep -w ".gitignore" | xargs ls -lh
```

After that:

```
find | grep -w ".gitignore" | xargs rm -fr
```